# Are some events "permanent"?

Tags: dont-get-fired

If you answer in a positive manner to some events, will they be flagged as being settled for the remaining of the game? For instance, if I decide to pay my student loan (20k IIRC), or buy my mom a purse (10k), will these events pop up again during the game? And if they are indeed marked as being settled, is the bonus they give permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am unsure about the positive and negative options towards team members, but once you pay off the student loans, or buy a purse for your mother, they do not pop up again

Answer (score 1):

Each of those large purchases has a positive consequence on your monetary social status, usually giving a permanent promotion chance increase. This includes buying a car, home, and getting married. Buying mom a purse does as well.

Answer (score 1):

You get a better promotion chance of 3%. But if you get fired, you will lose these 3% and theme event won't pop up again .

Answer (score 1):

The events like buying a car, house or getting married give you permanent bonus and won't pop up again.

Paying up the student loan will stop the pop-up to show up, but doesn't give you additional benefits.

In case of the purse, you get temporary boost in promotion chance of 3%, but it is not permanent. It doesn't look as a good investment, but it won't drain your promotion chance periodically anymore on the other hand.

Answer (score -1):

Buying her a purse gives you a permanent 3% promotion chance I think

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. If you don't have any strong reference to support your answer, then I would recommend not posting this answer if _you think_ it is correct. This site is intended to be a reference site, which is different from a forum. You answer, in its current version, is a better fit on a forum than here.